# MergeQueue missing some values in return statement

Tags: java

The **purpose of my method** is to merge the 2 sorted queue together into a bigger sorted queue of letters A - Z and return it. My method works for the most part (i.e. returns A-Z) However **sometimes it misses the letters Y, Z or sometimes just the letter Z itself in my return queue**. Here is an example of what I am saying.  
  
**Example** of the q1 and q2 that will produce a missing Y and Z in result queue.  
q1 is queue of strings that contain (A C E H I J K M N P Q R S T U X Y Z)  
q2 is queue of strings that contain (B D F G L O V W)  
These 2 parameters passed into my merge method.

```
 private static Queue<Comparable> merge(Queue<Comparable> q1, 
                                       Queue<Comparable> q2) {
    Queue<Comparable> q3 = new Queue<Comparable>();
    while (!q1.isEmpty() && !q2.isEmpty()){
        if (less(q1.peek(),q2.peek())) q3.enqueue(q1.dequeue());
        else if (less(q2.peek(),q1.peek())) q3.enqueue(q2.dequeue());
        if (q1.isEmpty() && !q2.isEmpty()) q3.enqueue(q2.dequeue());
        else if (q2.isEmpty() && !q1.isEmpty()) q3.enqueue(q1.dequeue());
    }
    //while (!q1.isEmpty()) q3.enqueue(q1.dequeue());
    //while (!q2.isEmpty()) q3.enqueue(q2.dequeue());
    return q3;
}
```

**What I've tried** to fix this problem is

```
while (!q1.isEmpty()) q3.enqueue(q1.dequeue());
while (!q2.isEmpty()) q3.enqueue(q2.dequeue());
```

and it solved it! However I am not comfortable with this solution. I figure it out by debugging with System.out.println to the code above this one to see if q1 and q2 is empty after the initial while loop. In this case q1 is not empty after the initial while loop ends. So I know that the problem lies somewhere within my conditional statements, but not sure where. My logic is a bit off.

  
**But I just don't understand** how the implementation above  this code leaves out Y and Z because the loop keeps going until both q1 and q2 is empty. If Y and Z is not enqueued to q3 then that means q1 still holds Y and Z and clearly **not empty** and the code should continue running until q1 is empty.

**Can someone explain how q1 did not enqueue Y and Z into q3? And how do
I fix it with a more efficient coding than the solution I've found.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The condition of your `while` loop is `!q1.isEmpty() && !q2.isEmpty()` - that is, that neither queue can be empty. This is a correct condition, because the loop body peeks into both queues and would fail if either queue were empty. However, if all elements in one queue are smaller than some elements of the other queue, those elements will be left in the other queue after the loop terminates. However, since you only remove one element from one of the queues in each iteration, one of the queues will empty before the other. So after the loop, exactly one queue will be empty and the other will not.

Therefore, the final operations must be to move all elements from the non-empty queue into the result queue. Since you know that exactly one queue will be empty, it's safe to do this by adding all elements from both queues, since adding all elements of an empty queue will have no effect.

Comment: A sequence of loops is not the same thing as a nested loop. Even without your if statements, you have a sequence of loops, and in this particular situation, you know that only one of the loops is going to execute at least one iteration; therefore, you don't need the ifs. (As a matter of fact, a `while` is essentially an `if` with a "jump-back-to-the-top" instruction at the end. I think you mixed up some variable names in your comment, but even so, the if statements are redundant, because their condition is checked again by the loops.)

Comment: (My previous comment was a response to a now-deleted comment by the OP.)